# malihu custom scrollbar puts <div class='mCSB_draggerRail'></div> in wrong place on electron

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, electron, mcustomscrollbar

malihu custom scrollbar puts `<div class='mCSB_draggerRail'></div>` in wrong place on electron.
I looked at the versions in my browser and it works just fine. HTML Code it generates looks something like this:

```html
<div class="servers-container mCustomScrollbar _mCS_1" style="overflow: auto;" data-mcs-theme="light-thick">
        <div id="mCSB_1" class="mCustomScrollBox mCS-light-thick mCSB_vertical mCSB_inside" style="max-height: none;"
            tabindex="0">
            <div id="mCSB_1_container" class="mCSB_container" style="position: relative; top: 0px; left: 0px;"
                dir="ltr">
                <div class="servers">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="mCSB_1_scrollbar_vertical"
                class="mCSB_scrollTools mCSB_1_scrollbar mCS-light-thick mCSB_scrollTools_vertical"
                style="display: block;">
                <div class="mCSB_draggerContainer">
                    <div id="mCSB_1_dragger_vertical" class="mCSB_dragger"
                        style="position: absolute; min-height: 30px; top: 0px; display: block; height: 372px; max-height: 495px;">
                        <div class="mCSB_dragger_bar" style="line-height: 30px;"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="mCSB_draggerRail"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

But in electron itself, it generates  inside  which leads to funky behaviour...

Here is what it generates in electron itself:

```html
<div class="servers-container mCustomScrollbar _mCS_1" style="overflow: auto;" data-mcs-theme="light-thick">
        <div id="mCSB_1" class="mCustomScrollBox mCS-light-thick mCSB_vertical mCSB_inside" style="max-height: none;"
            tabindex="0">
            <div id="mCSB_1_container" class="mCSB_container" style="position: relative; top: 0px; left: 0px;"
                dir="ltr">
                <div class="servers">

                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="mCSB_1_scrollbar_vertical"
                class="mCSB_scrollTools mCSB_1_scrollbar mCS-light-thick mCSB_scrollTools_vertical"
                style="display: block;">
                <div class="mCSB_draggerContainer">
                    <div id="mCSB_1_dragger_vertical" class="mCSB_dragger"
                        style="position: absolute; min-height: 30px; display: block; height: 77px; max-height: 316px; top: 0px;">
                        <div class="mCSB_dragger_bar" style="line-height: 30px;"></div>
                        <div class="mCSB_draggerRail"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Here is code which i used to implement this scrollbar:

```html
<script defer src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script defer src="js/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.concat.min.js"></script>
    <script defer src="renderer.js"></script>
    <script>
        const $ = require('jquery');
        require("jquery-mousewheel")($);
        require("malihu-custom-scrollbar-plugin")($);

        (function($){
        $(window).load(function(){
            $(".horizontalScrollbar").mCustomScrollbar({
                    scrollButtons:{ enable:false },
                    horizontalScroll:true,
                    advanced:{autoExpandHorizontalScroll:true}
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Also it gives `Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined` error any time i run it. I have no idea what is going on pls help.

P.S. If anything is needed to solve this mystery, i'll attach it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved this issue.

Jinixx uploaded a fix for this issue:
[malihu-custom-scrollbar-plugin 3.1.7](https://github.com/jinixx/malihu-custom-scrollbar-plugin/tree/3.1.7)

This issue caused by new jQuery 3.5.x that included some breaking changes. ([source](https://github.com/malihu/malihu-custom-scrollbar-plugin/issues/652))

Comment: I downloaded and replaced jquery.mCustomScrollbar.min css and js file but this behavior is still there (mCSB_draggerRail inside)

Comment: Jinixx solution worked for me with jQuery 3.6.0. Thanks, @Eden for the referral.